# Get cookies from selenium to requests

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I can login to a website with selenium and i can receive all cookies.
But then I have to quickly submit a request to the site. Meanwhile, selenium stays very slow.
That's why I want to receive cookies with selenium and send requests via the request module.

My Selenium Code (First I log in to the website and received all cookies with the code below.)

```
browser.get('https://www.example.com/login')
cookiem1 = browser.get_cookies()
print(cookiem1)
```

2nd stage, I will go to another page of the website and make a request.

```
s = requests.Session()
for cookie in cookiem1:
   s.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])
   r = s.get("https://example.com/postcomment')
   print(r.content)
```

I use cookies in this way, but when I send the url via request module, the site does not autohorize my user.

My error:
"errorMessage": "Unauthorized user",\r\n  "errorDetails": "No cookie"

Probably with this code the site doesn't unauthorized my session

Thanks in advance

Comment: You just need to check documentation of [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#cookies) and [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.7.0/user/quickstart/#cookies).

Comment: @OlvinRoght I read. But still i didn't do it. My question is how can i transfer from selenium cookie to requests module.

Comment: Try to unindent 2 last lines.

Comment: @OlvinRoght i tried but still same.i can't use the session i get wih selenium 
                                                                                                                     
           callback({\r\n  "errorMessage": "Unauthorized user",\r\n  "errorDetails": "No cookie"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    import requests as re
    ck = browser.get_cookies()
    s = re.Session()
    c = [s.cookies.set(c['name'], c['value']) for c in ck]
    response = s.get("https://example.com/postcomment")
```

Comment: Just use `s.cookies.update({c['name']: c['value'] for c in ck})`