# Passing cookies from Selenium to Python Requests

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, python-requests

I am making a Python 3-script with Selenium 4 and Gecko web driver.
I am using `cookies = driver.get_cookies()` to capture cookies after logging in to a site.

The question is how I can cookies from Selenium in a GET request using the [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module.
In other words, how can we capture cookies with Selenium and use those cookies in Requests?

I tried the suggested answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64401565/get-cookies-from-selenium-to-requests) question, but it is not correct and the question is over a year old without any other answers...

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532784/error-when-loading-cookies-into-a-python-request-session/59843387#59843387) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59951304/how-to-save-login-data-to-be-recognized-for-python-selenium-webdriver/59957467#59957467) discussion helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
requests_cookies = {}
for c in cookies:
    requests_cookies[c['name']] = c['value']    

response = requests.get('http://some-host...', cookies=requests_cookies)
```

**Reference:**

https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-share-cookies-between-selenium-and-requests-in-python-d36c3c8768b

Comment: This worked! Although I completely forgot to add a credible `User-Agent` to the request header and was quickly rejected from the site  Once I added it worked. Thanks!